# Variable Includes in Linq to Sql EF statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to have a variable amount of Includes in an EF Linq query?

Currently I have something like:

```
Form form = db.Forms.Where(m => m.Id == formId).Include("Child").First();
```

But is it possible to wrap this like:

```
GetFormWithIncludes(int formId, string[] includes)
{
    Form form = db.Forms.Where(m => m.Id == formId).Include("Each").Include("String").Include("In").Include("includes").First();
}
```

So that each string parameter in `includes` gets included?

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var entity = db.Forms;

foreach (string s in includes)
{
    entity.Include(s);
}

Form form = entity.Where(m => m.Id == id).First();
```

Comment: Why didn't you give the accepted answer to [BradD](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27452703) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head I don't see why something like this wouldn't work.

```
var query = db.Forms.Where(m => m.Id == formId);

foreach(string s in includes)
{
    query = query.Include(s);
}

Form form = query.First();
```

Normal caveats apply. If a string in the includes array isn't a navigation property EF will throw an exception and such.

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea!  The include function comes from the DbQuery object rather than the IQueryable, so I had to change it a bit.